# How to run an infinite loop which gives correct result? C++

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, visual-c++, infinite-loop

I want to run an infinite loop which prints the power of the integer 2, namely 2,4,8,16. I have written this code but it is not working correctly in a loop it is giving **0** as answer. However, It works fine without loop means it gives the single answer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=2,power=1,i=1;
    while(i>0)
    {
    power*=n;
    cout<<power;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not infinite if it has a termination condition that can be met.

Comment: @tadman I'd agree with that, but this particular loop has a termination condition that cannot be met (without the help of cosmic radiation).

Comment: While loop will never get end, its infinite loop. why can't you initialize variable i with some number like 10 and decrements it in while loop and run it to see the result.

Comment: @John Oh, I misread it as `i` being `power`. In fact `i` is a red herring. This should be `while (1)` or as Sanjeev points out, a more reasonable limit.

Comment: Hint: Integers in C++ do not hold infinitely large values, they have [very specific ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: Complete the following plain-language sentence: "I want to output powers of 2 until ____________". Translate that into code only after you have your well-defined requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program does not just output zeroes when I run it.  It outputs powers of two for a while, before an overflow causes it to start outputting zeros.

First, add line breaks so you can more easily tell what is happening:

```
cout << power << endl;
```

Then try piping the output of your program into `less` or `head -n40` so you can see the beginning of its output:

```
$ ./test | head -n40
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
-2147483648
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: It is important though that there is no guarantee for this particular kind of output. The signed integer overflow causes UB and the compiler could let the program do anything.

Comment: That's right.  It would be good to switch to an unsigned integer or do something else to fix the undefined behavior.  Using GCC's `-fwrapv` option is another option.

Comment: Thanks @DavidGrayson your solution really helped, I was not focusing on the fact that I also have to focus on the limits of integers. However, I want to know that when I run this program on an online compiler then it displays only 0s from the beginning to the end, why is that? It executes same as you said on an offline compiler.

Comment: I don't know why that is, but I suspect that it is a consequence of the undefined behavior or you just haven't figured out how to view the beginning of the output.  If you're using an online compiler it's probably best to avoid infinite output; try terminating your loop after 40 iterations instead.

Comment: Okay Thanks. @DavidGrayson

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your loop will overflow the maximum `int` value when repeatedly multiplying by n, which leads to undefined behavior.  You need to check your loop to avoid the overflow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int n=2,power=1;
    while(power <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max()/n)
    {
        power *= n;
        std::cout << power << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDodd your solution really helped, I was not focusing on the fact that I also have to focus on the limits of integers.